# Scala: How to ignore 'SSLHandshakeException'

Tags: scala, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

With such code:

```
val html = Source.fromURL("https://scans.io/json")
```

Getting exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
...
```

I can find how to fix in Java but have no idea - how to fix it in Scala?

Comment: The underlying api can't verify the certificate with a certificate authority. Is it self-signed?

Comment: It opens ok in browser. But anyway - how to ignore error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this by configuring a `SSLContext`.

Here is a working code

```
import javax.net.ssl._
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
import scala.io.Source

// Bypasses both client and server validation.
object TrustAll extends X509TrustManager {
  val getAcceptedIssuers = null

  override def checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates: Array[X509Certificate], s: String) = {}

  override def checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates: Array[X509Certificate], s: String) = {}
}

// Verifies all host names by simply returning true.
object VerifiesAllHostNames extends HostnameVerifier {
  def verify(s: String, sslSession: SSLSession) = true
}

// Main class
object Test extends App {
  // SSL Context initialization and configuration
  val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
  sslContext.init(null, Array(TrustAll), new java.security.SecureRandom())
  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory)
  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(VerifiesAllHostNames)
  
  // Actual call
  val html = Source.fromURL("https://scans.io/json")
  println(html.mkString)
}
```

### How it works

`Source.fromURL` uses `java.net.HttpURLConnection` behind the scene. So this code simply works because `TrustAll` bypasses `checkClientTrusted` and `checkServerTrusted` methods.

Comment: By the way I would never do this, especially in production, unless you have a real reason behind this (temporary, just for testing, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, it works!
I see no other way to solve this. Except like add that certificate to trust store, but I prefer to just ignore that error. This is not secure information.

Comment: Bypassing is not recommended. Instead try to add the certificate to your trust-store as I mentioned below.

Comment: Note that creating the TrustAll object this way is not possible in scala 2.10 due to a bug (which has been fixed in 2.11): https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8011

In 2.10, this seems to work:
`class TrustAll extends X509TrustManager {
  override def getAcceptedIssuers: Array[X509Certificate] = {null}
  override def checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates: Array[X509Certificate], s: String): Unit = {}
  override def checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates: Array[X509Certificate], s: String): Unit = {}
}`

Comment: getting a ```java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name
  at java.lang.Class.getSimpleName(Class.java:1190)
  at java.lang.Class.getCanonicalName(Class.java:1233)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:540)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
  ...```